# Wrong data sent while Bluetoothgatt.writecharacterstic

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

My android device is connected to a BLE dongle. The BLE Dongle is sending me messages for example A at 20 to 40 milliseconds of interval. I am getting messages in onCharacterticChange method. I am modifying the messages to for eg. to B.  I am calling Bluetoothgatt.writeCharacterstic(characterstic) method at 20 to 40 millisecond interval to send messages B back to BLE dongle. I am sending near about 10,000 messages to BLE Dongle.  Some times instead of B ,the dongle is getting message A. That is very strange i don't know what is happening in the background?? How to prevent that. I hope anyone have answer to that.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code you are using to do all this.

Comment: I can't post code now as i am not having with me but just want to know if the bluetoothgatt.writecharacterstic(characterstic) can led to produce the written value in onCharactersticChange method??